# Javasript closure stange behaviour

Tags: javascript, closures

emphasized textHi I'm learning Javascripts closures and tjis code beahves funny to me:

```js
function Unique_id2() {
    let counter = 0;
    function f() { return counter++; };
    return f();
}

console.log("UID2");
let f = Unique_id2;
console.log(typeof f);
console.log(f());
console.log(f());
console.log(f());
console.log(f());
console.log(f());
```

the result is:

```
UID2
functions.js:65 function
functions.js:66 0
functions.js:67 0
functions.js:68 0
functions.js:69 0
functions.js:70 0
```

which is strangge to me since the counter souhld be incrementsd each time ...

can you explain what's wrong

**EDIT**

```
function Unique_id2() {
        let counter = 0;
        function f() { return counter++; };
        return f;
    }

    console.log("UID2");
    let f = Unique_id2;
    console.log(typeof f);
    console.log(Unique_id2()());
    console.log(Unique_id2()());
    console.log(Unique_id2()());
    console.log(Unique_id2()());
    console.log(Unique_id2()());
```

yields the same result

Comment: You probably just meant to `return f` instead of `return f()`, and then call that function that was returned multiple times…

Comment: `counter` is scoped to `Unique_id2` function, so it gets reset each time you call that.

Comment: In all your recent edits, you're still doing it wrong. The answer below shows you the one correct way. Just do exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning the closure, you're just calling it each time you call `Unique_id2()`. And each time you do that, it resets the counter to 0 and returns that.

To get an incrementing counter, you have to return the closure, not the result of calling it. Then you should call *that* closure repeatedly to get each incremented value.

So in the code below, you call `Unique_id2()` and assign that to a variable like `f` or `f2`. Then when you call `f()` you get the incrementing counter values.

```js
function Unique_id2() {
    let counter = 0;
    function f() { return counter++; };
    return f;
}

console.log("UID");
let f = Unique_id2();
console.log(typeof f);

console.log(f());
console.log(f());
console.log(f());
console.log(f());
console.log(f());

console.log("UID2");
let f2 = Unique_id2();
console.log(typeof f2);
console.log(f2());
console.log(f2());
```

Comment: I just get f() { counter++; }in return for each iteration

Comment: @Luca Yes, you get `f () {counter++}`. That's a function. So call it

Comment: @slebetman it's alteady a function-called with not args, if I call it again yields 0 for each iteration

Comment: @Luca Did you call `f()` of `f2()` like the answer above?

Comment: @Luca You would get that if you did `console.log(f)` instead of `console.log(f())`. Note the `()` after the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Even with different names and references, you're calling `Unique_id2` every time.

And every time it is invoked, the `Unique_id2` function initialises the variable `counter` to 0.

To achieve what you are trying to do, you need to move the initialisation of `counter` out of the `Unique_id2` scope, like this:

```js
let counter = 0;

function Unique_id2() {    
    function f() { return counter++; };
    return f;
}

console.log("UID");
let f = Unique_id2();
console.log(typeof f);

console.log(f());
console.log(f());
console.log(f());
console.log(f());
```

This way the `counter` variable is initialised only once, and thanks to the closure, the `Unique_id2` has access to it.